# Inter-Widget communication in Flutter (with Redux)

Tags: redux, flutter

I'm working on my first Flutter App that has multiple (custom) buttons in various places of the screen (some in the body of the Scaffold widget, some in the Bottom Navigation Bar). Those buttons only trigger an action if they get pressed for 0.5 seconds. In order to give the user some feedback, I also added a "progress bar" on the screen (only one progress bar for all those buttons!) that starts running if one of those buttons gets pressed (and the progress bar will be reset if the user stops holding the button).

The challenge I am facing now is how to start and stop the progress bar. Do you have some advice on how to tackle this problem?

By the way: for state management I apply the Redux pattern...

Thanks and regards!

Comment: You can try not using Redux. It might help. Also I'm sorry if this is not helpful.

Comment: What would be an alternative then?

Comment: If you're using something like `LinearProgressIndicator`, starting/stopping it can be done by using a animation controller and some status variable (there are already answers for this in SO). You say you're already using Redux, so I'm not sure what is your question. Without Redux you could pass a callback function to the widgets, so they can trigger the state changes.

Comment: Expose local state changes as observable streams. Expose events that should trigger things also as observable streams. Although in this particular case they *should* have a common parent controller of sorts, just not necessarily app-global.